Is 'in the same way' redundant '...in the same way as...'?
From [Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.532.]

The gradable vs non-gradable contrast applies with adverbs in the same
way as with adjectives.

Does deleting 'in the same way' have no influence on the meaning at all? 'as' has the same meaning as 'in the same way'.

"The gradable vs non-gradable contrast applies with adverbs as with adjectives." could mean it applies to the same types of adverbs as it does with adjectives, but in different ways. You should look up in the same way in some dictionaries.

@Stuart F Good, so they have very different meanings. You can write an answer.

It's true that including in the same way (often, in such contexts, in exactly the same way) doesn't significantly alter the basic meaning.
But it provides emphasis, which when used appropriately is an essential component of verbal communication.
The "minimalist" form ...applies with adverbs as with adjectives is slightly "stilted, formal, poetic" phrasing - a more natural form with perhaps less emphasis would be ...applies with adverbs as well as adjectives.1

1 We can "delete" predictably-repeated with after as well as, but we can't safely do this with ...applies with adverbs as adjectives, because that might be taken as meaning ...adverbs which are being used as adjectives.

Yes, "with adverbs as with adjectives" is so compact (or abrupt) that it conveys a figurative sense: “On earth as in heaven.” A few extra words will help round out the meaning.

The comment above of Stuart F has a different reading, so does this sentence have an ambiguity？

I have no idea what Stuart was getting at. Nothing in your cited text gives us any reason to think (same or different) types of adjectives or adverbs are relevant to the way in which the gradable vs non-gradable contrast applies. So far as I can see there's only the potential ambiguity I pointed out above (which arises only if you delete the predictably-repeated second instance of with as well as the "redundant" element in the same way).
